# Is there a setting in flow to prohibit the use of 'any' in an assignment?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Is there a way to ensure an error is generated in flow when a known type is assigned an `any` value?

```
// @flow strict
type MyType = {|
  propA: string
|};

const x: MyType = {
  propA: "Hello, Stackoverflow!" // Works.
};

const y: MyType = {
  propA: x[0] // Works, but I don't want it to.
};

const z: MyType = {
  propA: window.propDoesNotExist // Works, but I don't want it to.
};
```

**.flowconfig**

```
...

[strict]
nonstrict-import
unclear-type
unsafe-getters-setters
untyped-import
untyped-type-import
```

I would like to make `propA` be extra strict such that only known `string` values are allowed.

Comment: Properly type the `window` object maybe?

Comment: I'm using `window` as an example. I updated the question to include an alternate way of getting an `any` value with an indexer.

Comment: Is flow considering the bracket property accessor as dynamic and therefore assuming it can't analyze it?

Comment: @JamesKraus, yes it's considered a type of `any`, and that's allowed as the value of a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the type for a key and value of an object:

[Flow documentation: Object as maps](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps)

If you need strict keys:

```
type Enum = 'propA' | 'propB';
type MyType = {
  [Enum]: string
};
```

If you don't need strict keys:

```
type MyType = {
  [string]: string
};
```

Quote from documentation:

> An indexer can be optionally named, for documentation purposes:

```
type MyType = {
  [propA: string]: string
};
```

[Flow try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHdQGcAuAnAlgYxQKFygJ4AOApqAKIB2ArgLagC8oA5MWrMQIIugA+rdpwBCLANwES5ALKEAKlKagA3rlCgA2tXoBdAFzJ0GKgHNcAXwm4ssKqlDxjAEwRLlKUqgMAWAEyX8GzsUUAAPA1kFMjc1UCFuAwAiAAlSaDgAGlAAZRQAQywAa1gAN1I0GAQAQkSMiysg+0II+UVmVXV4rgNQjQAGHSyQUAB1WDRCpCyAIxoQgElQFyoWEPg8qhCMEJRYADp6wNt7AC8WqPJ22K6DRyoXeD34gBFYTwA5WBQKUIx7YbGEymoFmCyWtlWDg2Wx2+0OuGGAHkAEr4IjRSJSXwxdQaG6GTCmfQE4xmALWY4hAD64VAmLI2KunQ4CVYHlQLDqzJEPl89SAA)

Edit: trigger an error on any usage => [strict mode](https://flow.org/en/docs/strict/#toc-features)

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know. It still doesn't strictly prohibit `any` being used to set a known value `propA = unknownAnyVar;`

Comment: You can prohibit any in your entire project by setting your flow in [strict mode](https://flow.org/en/docs/strict/#toc-features)